# How to make the last heading level 1 as running head at recto page in current page?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I'am facing an issue in recto page running head. Whenever there was more than one Heading level 1 on same recto page, last Heading level 1 was not updated in `\@oddhead`. Each time, I was manually changing the running head using `\markright` command.

I am not using `fancyheadings` and `fancyhdr` packages. I am manually re-defining the command `\ps@headings`. Please see my TeX code below

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[authoryear,comma,longnamesfirst,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nut}{\hspace{.5em}}
\def \@setfolio #1{%
  {\sffamily\bfseries\small #1}}
\def \ps@headings {%
  \def \@evenhead {\hskip-88\p@\@setfolio{\thepage}\hspace*{11.3pt}\fontsize{9.5pt}{9.5pt}\selectfont\leftmark\hfill}%
  \let \@evenfoot = \@empty
  \def \@oddhead {\hfill\fontsize{9.5pt}{9.5pt}\selectfont\rightmark\hspace*{10.5pt}\@setfolio{\thepage}}%
  \let \@oddfoot = \@empty
  \let \@mkboth = \markboth
  \def \chaptermark ##1{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \@chapapp\ \thechapter\kern7pt %\quad
        \fi
      \fi
      \emph{##1}}{}}%
  \def \sectionmark ##1{%
    \markright{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
        %\raisebox{15pt}{
    \thesection%}
    \nut
      \fi
      ##1}}}
\ps@headings
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This was the Sample Title}

\section{01 - Sample Heading 1} \label{sec:1.1}
\lipsum[1-7]


\section{02 - Sample Heading 1}\label{sec:1.2}
\lipsum[1]

\section{03 - Sample Heading 1}\label{sec:1.3}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Please refer the image Yellow highlighted on running head. I need to change from **1.2 02 - Sample Heading 1 3** to **1.3 03 - Sample Heading 1**.

[image]

How to do this kind of update without using `\markright` at each time?

Comment: Replace `\rightmark` by `\LastMark{2e-right}` or define and use `\rightlastmark`:  `\def \rightlastmark {\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}`. Then the last right mark on the page is used in page header.

Comment: @esdd - Its worked. Many Thanks..